# GEOPOINT support in Cloud Datastore GQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, gql, geopoints

The GQL reference [mentions](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference#python_gql_for_app_engine_differences) upcoming support for a `GEOPOINT` function in Cloud Datastore GQL. Can we expect it in the near future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110449984) opened for that. You can follow this issue over the official issue tracker.